# Workspace feature broken in version 29?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I was successfully using the "workspace" feature introduced with the Chrome canary version 28...
After updating to the Version 29.0.1547.57 m I can't find a way to make the feature to work again.

I mainly use it to edit css files and they won't save the changes like it did before.

My laptop is affected by the same issue.

Also the "File system folders in source panel" option is gone. As you can see in a previous version tutorial [here](http://devcoma.blogspot.it/2013/01/how-to-enable-workspace-experiment-on.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

Before it was set like this

```
Folder : D:\xampp\htdocs\mysite.dev
```

Mapping

```
Url prefix : http:\\www.mysite.dev
Folder path : D:\xampp\htdocs\mysite.dev/
```

with the new version, a simple "/" is enough as the Folder path.